# Google Tv app-How to implement of MOUSE pointer on WEBVIEW navigation controlled from D-pad?

Tags: webview, d-pad

Implementing the Webview based application for Android TV with no of links to the website landing on Video pages. The web page being desktop, it is very difficult to use the D-Pad keys to navigate. I would like to implement the Mouse cursor kind of navigation controlled by D-Pad. Any help to available sample source code would help.

Comment: Please did you find a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do the same thing here.

---

**Basic approach:**

- Create a custom view that draws, moves and animates a cursor
- In a Frame Layout add this custom cursor view on top of your webview
- When the user clicks (key: DPAD center), simulate a click on the position of your cursor via simulated touch events
- Scroll the WebView on a corresponding button press when the cursor is at the edge

---

**The focus handling is a bit of a PITA when doing this, though:**

The webview does all kinds of weird stuff (scrolling, highlighting,...) when it has focus. So I tried having my cursor view focused. Works perfectly fine, except when it comes to clicking text input fields -> keyboard won't show/work if the WebView isn't focused.

So, using getHitTestResult() we can find out if our click will hit an input field and make the WebView have focus before. That works fine, but I haven't yet found a reliable way to hand the focus back to my cursor view when the user is done entering text.

One thing I tried was getting a hook on the IME connection, but I couldn't quite get this approach to be stable enough for using it in a public app.

Answer (score 0):

To Enable cursor pointer in android tv webview by creating custom pointer layout

```
public class CursorLayout extends FrameLayout {
public static final int CURSOR_DISAPPEAR_TIMEOUT = 5000;
public static int CURSOR_RADIUS = 0;
public static float CURSOR_STROKE_WIDTH = 0.0f;
public static float MAX_CURSOR_SPEED = 0.0f;
public static int SCROLL_START_PADDING = 100;
public static final int UNCHANGED = -100;
public int EFFECT_DIAMETER;
public int EFFECT_RADIUS;
private Callback callback;
/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public Point cursorDirection = new Point(0, 0);
/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public Runnable cursorHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        CursorLayout.this.invalidate();
    }
};
/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public PointF cursorPosition = new PointF(0.0f, 0.0f);
/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public PointF cursorSpeed = new PointF(0.0f, 0.0f);
private Runnable cursorUpdateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (CursorLayout.this.getHandler() != null) {
            CursorLayout.this.getHandler().removeCallbacks(CursorLayout.this.cursorHideRunnable);
        }
        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long access$100 = currentTimeMillis - CursorLayout.this.lastCursorUpdate;
        CursorLayout.this.lastCursorUpdate = currentTimeMillis;
        float f = ((float) access$100) * 0.05f;
        PointF access$200 = CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed;
        CursorLayout cursorLayout = CursorLayout.this;
        float f2 = cursorLayout.cursorSpeed.x;
        CursorLayout cursorLayout2 = CursorLayout.this;
        float access$400 = cursorLayout.bound(f2 + (cursorLayout2.bound((float) cursorLayout2.cursorDirection.x, 1.0f) * f), CursorLayout.MAX_CURSOR_SPEED);
        CursorLayout cursorLayout3 = CursorLayout.this;
        float f3 = cursorLayout3.cursorSpeed.y;
        CursorLayout cursorLayout4 = CursorLayout.this;
        access$200.set(access$400, cursorLayout3.bound(f3 + (cursorLayout4.bound((float) cursorLayout4.cursorDirection.y, 1.0f) * f), CursorLayout.MAX_CURSOR_SPEED));
        if (Math.abs(CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x) < 0.1f) {
            CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x = 0.0f;
        }
        if (Math.abs(CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y) < 0.1f) {
            CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y = 0.0f;
        }
        if (CursorLayout.this.cursorDirection.x == 0 && CursorLayout.this.cursorDirection.y == 0 && CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x == 0.0f && CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y == 0.0f) {
            if (CursorLayout.this.getHandler() != null) {
                CursorLayout.this.getHandler().postDelayed(CursorLayout.this.cursorHideRunnable, 5000);
            }
            return;
        }
        CursorLayout.this.tmpPointF.set(CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition);
        CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.offset(CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x, CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y);
        Log.d("cursor1234_xxxx", String.valueOf(CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.x));
        Log.d("cursor1234_yyyy", String.valueOf(CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.y));
        if (CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.x < 0.0f) {
            CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.x = 0.0f;
        } else if (CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.x > ((float) (CursorLayout.this.getWidth() - 1))) {
            CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.x = (float) (CursorLayout.this.getWidth() - 1);
        }
        if (CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.y < 0.0f) {
            CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.y = 0.0f;
        } else if (CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.y > ((float) (CursorLayout.this.getHeight() - 1))) {
            CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.y = (float) (CursorLayout.this.getHeight() - 1);
        }
        if (!CursorLayout.this.tmpPointF.equals(CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition) && CursorLayout.this.dpadCenterPressed) {
            CursorLayout cursorLayout5 = CursorLayout.this;
            cursorLayout5.dispatchMotionEvent(cursorLayout5.cursorPosition.x, CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.y, 2);
        }
        View childAt = CursorLayout.this.getChildAt(0);
        if (childAt != null) {
            if (CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.y > ((float) (CursorLayout.this.getHeight() - CursorLayout.SCROLL_START_PADDING))) {
                if (CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y > 0.0f && childAt.canScrollVertically((int) CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y)) {
                    childAt.scrollTo(childAt.getScrollX(), childAt.getScrollY() + ((int) CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y));
                }
            } else if (CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.y < ((float) CursorLayout.SCROLL_START_PADDING) && CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y < 0.0f && childAt.canScrollVertically((int) CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y)) {
                childAt.scrollTo(childAt.getScrollX(), childAt.getScrollY() + ((int) CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.y));
            }
            if (CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.x > ((float) (CursorLayout.this.getWidth() - CursorLayout.SCROLL_START_PADDING))) {
                if (CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x > 0.0f && childAt.canScrollHorizontally((int) CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x)) {
                    childAt.scrollTo(childAt.getScrollX() + ((int) CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x), childAt.getScrollY());
                }
            } else if (CursorLayout.this.cursorPosition.x < ((float) CursorLayout.SCROLL_START_PADDING) && CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x < 0.0f && childAt.canScrollHorizontally((int) CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x)) {
                childAt.scrollTo(childAt.getScrollX() + ((int) CursorLayout.this.cursorSpeed.x), childAt.getScrollY());
            }
        }
        CursorLayout.this.invalidate();
        if (CursorLayout.this.getHandler() != null) {
            CursorLayout.this.getHandler().post(this);
        }
    }
};
/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public boolean dpadCenterPressed = false;
/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public long lastCursorUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
private Paint paint = new Paint();
PointF tmpPointF = new PointF();

public interface Callback {
    void onUserInteraction();
}

/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public float bound(float f, float f2) {
    if (f > f2) {
        return f2;
    }
    float f3 = -f2;
    return f < f3 ? f3 : f;
}

public CursorLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CursorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        Display defaultDisplay = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        Point point = new Point();
        defaultDisplay.getSize(point);
        this.EFFECT_RADIUS = point.x / 20;
        this.EFFECT_DIAMETER = this.EFFECT_RADIUS * 2;
        CURSOR_STROKE_WIDTH = (float) (point.x / 400);
        CURSOR_RADIUS = point.x / 110;
        MAX_CURSOR_SPEED = (float) (point.x / 25);
        SCROLL_START_PADDING = point.x / 15;
    }
}

public void setCallback(Callback callback2) {
    this.callback = callback2;
}

public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    Callback callback2 = this.callback;
    if (callback2 != null) {
        callback2.onUserInteraction();
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

/* access modifiers changed from: protected */
public void onSizeChanged(int i, int i2, int i3, int i4) {
    super.onSizeChanged(i, i2, i3, i4);
    UtilMethods.LogMethod("cursorView123_", "onSizeChanged");
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        this.cursorPosition.set(((float) i) / 2.0f, ((float) i2) / 2.0f);
        if (getHandler() != null) {
            getHandler().postDelayed(this.cursorHideRunnable, 5000);
        }
    }
}

public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    UtilMethods.LogMethod("cursorView123_", "dispatchKeyEvent");
    Callback callback2 = this.callback;
    if (callback2 != null) {
        callback2.onUserInteraction();
    }
    int keyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
    if (!(keyCode == 66 || keyCode == 160)) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case 19:
                if (keyEvent.getAction() == 0) {
                    if (this.cursorPosition.y <= 0.0f) {
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(keyEvent);
                    }
                    handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, -100, -1, true);
                } else if (keyEvent.getAction() == 1) {
                    handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, -100, 0, false);
                }
                return true;
            case 20:
                if (keyEvent.getAction() == 0) {
                    if (this.cursorPosition.y >= ((float) getHeight())) {
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(keyEvent);
                    }
                    handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, -100, 1, true);
                } else if (keyEvent.getAction() == 1) {
                    handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, -100, 0, false);
                }
                return true;
            case 21:
                if (keyEvent.getAction() == 0) {
                    if (this.cursorPosition.x <= 0.0f) {
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(keyEvent);
                    }
                    handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, -1, -100, true);
                } else if (keyEvent.getAction() == 1) {
                    handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, 0, -100, false);
                }
                return true;
            case 22:
                if (keyEvent.getAction() == 0) {
                    if (this.cursorPosition.x >= ((float) getWidth())) {
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(keyEvent);
                    }
                    handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, 1, -100, true);
                } else if (keyEvent.getAction() == 1) {
                    handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, 0, -100, false);
                }
                return true;
            case 23:
                break;
            default:
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case 268:
                        if (keyEvent.getAction() == 0) {
                            handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, -1, -1, true);
                        } else if (keyEvent.getAction() == 1) {
                            handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, 0, 0, false);
                        }
                        return true;
                    case 269:
                        if (keyEvent.getAction() == 0) {
                            handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, -1, 1, true);
                        } else if (keyEvent.getAction() == 1) {
                            handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, 0, 0, false);
                        }
                        return true;
                    case 270:
                        if (keyEvent.getAction() == 0) {
                            handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, 1, -1, true);
                        } else if (keyEvent.getAction() == 1) {
                            handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, 0, 0, false);
                        }
                        return true;
                    case 271:
                        if (keyEvent.getAction() == 0) {
                            handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, 1, 1, true);
                        } else if (keyEvent.getAction() == 1) {
                            handleDirectionKeyEvent(keyEvent, 0, 0, false);
                        }
                        return true;
                }
        }
    }
    if (!isCursorDissappear()) {
        if (keyEvent.getAction() == 0 && !getKeyDispatcherState().isTracking(keyEvent)) {
            getKeyDispatcherState().startTracking(keyEvent, this);
            this.dpadCenterPressed = true;
            dispatchMotionEvent(this.cursorPosition.x, this.cursorPosition.y, 0);
        } else if (keyEvent.getAction() == 1) {
            getKeyDispatcherState().handleUpEvent(keyEvent);
            dispatchMotionEvent(this.cursorPosition.x, this.cursorPosition.y, 1);
            this.dpadCenterPressed = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(keyEvent);
}

/* access modifiers changed from: private */
public void dispatchMotionEvent(float f, float f2, int i) {
    UtilMethods.LogMethod("cursorView123_", "dispatchMotionEvent");
    long uptimeMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long uptimeMillis2 = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    PointerProperties pointerProperties = new PointerProperties();
    pointerProperties.id = 0;
    pointerProperties.toolType = 1;
    PointerProperties[] pointerPropertiesArr = {pointerProperties};
    PointerCoords pointerCoords = new PointerCoords();
    pointerCoords.x = f;
    pointerCoords.y = f2;
    pointerCoords.pressure = 1.0f;
    pointerCoords.size = 1.0f;
    dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(uptimeMillis, uptimeMillis2, i, 1, pointerPropertiesArr, new PointerCoords[]{pointerCoords}, 0, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0));
}

private void handleDirectionKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent, int i, int i2, boolean z) {
    this.lastCursorUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (!z) {
        getKeyDispatcherState().handleUpEvent(keyEvent);
        this.cursorSpeed.set(0.0f, 0.0f);
    } else if (!getKeyDispatcherState().isTracking(keyEvent)) {
        Handler handler = getHandler();
        handler.removeCallbacks(this.cursorUpdateRunnable);
        handler.post(this.cursorUpdateRunnable);
        getKeyDispatcherState().startTracking(keyEvent, this);
    } else {
        return;
    }
    Point point = this.cursorDirection;
    if (i == -100) {
        i = point.x;
    }
    if (i2 == -100) {
        i2 = this.cursorDirection.y;
    }
    point.set(i, i2);
}

/* access modifiers changed from: protected */
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    UtilMethods.LogMethod("cursorView123_", "dispatchDraw");
    if (!isInEditMode() && !isCursorDissappear()) {
        float f = this.cursorPosition.x;
        float f2 = this.cursorPosition.y;
        this.paint.setColor(Color.argb(128, 255, 255, 255));
        this.paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(f, f2, (float) CURSOR_RADIUS, this.paint);
        this.paint.setColor(-7829368);
        this.paint.setStrokeWidth(CURSOR_STROKE_WIDTH);
        this.paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawCircle(f, f2, (float) CURSOR_RADIUS, this.paint);
    }
}

private boolean isCursorDissappear() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - this.lastCursorUpdate > 5000;
}

/* access modifiers changed from: protected */
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}}
```

then put the webview inside custom cursor layout in XML

```
<com.example.webviewtvapp.CursorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cursorLayout">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</com.example.webviewtvapp.CursorLayout>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)